What jet is this?

Anyone have any idea what jet is this? From the picture it seems to British and it also looks like it's from the 1950s or 1960s. But other than that I couldn't identify the type.

It is actually the third prototype which flew first in 1947!

I thought I left a comment here containing information explaining how to get the answer to such questions.

That is a de Havilland DH108, which is possibly most notable for the crash that killed its pilot, Geoffrey de Havilland Jr., son of the founder of de Havilland Aircraft Company.
Only 3 prototypes were ever built, and all three crashed.

It does resemble the German me163.

@WenHuiWong ... but was even more lethal to its pilots. All three prototypes crashed.
